# How to send a GET/POST request with Forth

Tags: sockets, raspberry-pi, forth

I want to write a Forth program for my Raspberry Pi. This program shall read some sensor data from an existing file and send it to a website where the data gets stored.

Searching the web there was plenty of documentation about how easy and fast Forth is and how to calculate Fibonacci numbers. But how can I request a URL? How can I send data to a website and process the result?

If there's no socket support: is it possible to start an external program like curl/wget to do the request?

Comment: Good question (that I don't know the answer to). For Gforth (that I have actually installed on a Raspberry Pi), on [their page](https://www.gnu.org/software/gforth/), under *"libraries"* it lists *"httpd.fs, a web server (undocumented) "* - so I presume there is access to sockets.

Comment: [My installation instructions for Gforth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869836/load-from-the-terminal-input-buffer-to-parameter-stack/27891510#27891510) (at the end of the answer).

Comment: I've just found an example on rosettacode. And another question regarding this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602466/forth-networking-library

Comment: Does the Raspberry Pi come provide any documentation regarding their Forth implementation? It's all about what Forth words they may be providing in a library for their Forth. What GForth libraries are available probably won't help you unless you wanted to port an implementation from that domain yourself.

Comment: It is important to mention what Forth implementation do you use on Raspberry Pi? Since the sockets is not part of the standard the network libraries and APIs depend on implementation.

Comment: Here is the example from Rosettacode: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/HTTP#Forth It works with "include unix/socket.fs"

Answer (score 5):

It is not obvious from the question what the Forth implementation is used.

For example, Gforth (that is available on Raspberry Pi)
has some support of the sockets and also it allows to start an external program using `system` word. See my answer on the similar question: [How do I read raw code from a website in Gforth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48587263/how-do-i-read-raw-code-from-a-website-in-gforth)

Example of creating **curl** child process in Gforth:

```
S" curl https://example.com/" system
```

In any case,
it seems that the most promising approach for the given problem is to develop a binding to [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) (if it doesn't exist yet for the used Forth implementation).

Comment: The OP is running Forth on a Raspberry Pi. Does it have the same socket library available to it as Gforth?

Comment: @lurker, thanks — I really missed that the Forth implementation is not mentioned in the question. Now I have updated the answer accordingly. In case of using **libcurl** no need for a socket library.